# Phantom wallet : issue with transaction , web.js not enough solana

Tags: web3.js, phantom, phantom-wallet

Please help fix an issue  with phantom wallet
here is my  code

It's writing not enough solana, but I have enough

```
     var transaction = new solanaWeb3.Transaction().add(
          solanaWeb3.SystemProgram.transfer({
            fromPubkey: fromWallet,
            toPubkey: toWallet,
            lamports: 100  
          }),
        );

        transaction.feePayer = await provider.publicKey;
        let blockhashObj = await connection.getRecentBlockhash();
        transaction.recentBlockhash = await blockhashObj.blockhash;

        // Transaction constructor initialized successfully
        if(transaction) {
          console.log("Txn created successfully");
        }

  
      const { signature } = await provider.signAndSendTransaction(transaction);
     

        console.log("SIGNATURE", signature);
        console.log("SUCCESS");
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is fromWallet publickey ? are you sure this account has sol ?

Answer (score -1):

It appears that your lamport parameter is calculated incorrectly. Try this: `lamports: web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL / 100`